# Send button not retrieving friends bug?

Tags: facebook, send

I'm trying to implement the [Send button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/), but running into what may just be a user experience issue but certainly appears to be a bug.

At least on my machine, the same is happening on my site as well as the demo in the link above.

When you click the "To" field to enter a friend's name and start typing nothing shows up. It doesn't show the drop down of friends. Then if you click in the "Message" field and *go back* to the "To" field the drop down works.

Am I alone here?

Comment: You're right, looks like a bug

Comment: I submitted a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/326114077446802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I filed a Facebook bug report there was already an existing ticket. See this ticket for  the best updates: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/263204287096105